# Find the blank row after the last row then paste

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button to open another Excel file. Copy from there and paste certain columns onto this Excel file.

My code works when I use a steady range for the paste function (ex. A1 instead of Range("A" & lDestLastRow)).

I want to paste onto the next empty row.

```vb
Sub get_data_from_file()
    Dim FileToOpen as Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Dim wsdest as Worksheet
    Dim lDestLastRow as Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating=False
    Set wsdest = Workbooks("Test.xslm").Worksheets("Input Sheet")
    lDestLastRow=Sheet1.Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion.Row+1

    FileToOpen=Application.GetOpenFileName(Title:="Browse for your file and input range",
    FileFilter:"Excel Files (*xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen<>False Then

        SetOpenBook=Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1)Range(B:E).Copy
        wsdest.Range("A", lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1)Range(G:H).Copy
        wsdest.Range("E", lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1)Range(M:M).Copy
        wsdest.Range("G", lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End if
    Application.ScreenUpdating=True
End Sub
```

Comment: you need a space in `SetOpenBook` it should be `Set OpenBook`

Comment: `.Sheets(1)Range(B:E)` bust be `.Sheets(1).Range("B:E")`, others accordingly. Actually your code should throw more than one compilation error.

Comment: One cannot copy full columns and paste it in anything but the first row in the target sheet.  You will need to limit the copy range to the data only.

Comment: use something like: `Intersect(OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("B:E"),OpenBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange).Copy`

Answer (score 0):

1. This `lDestLastRow=Sheet1.Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion.Row+1` does not find the very last row of the entire sheet. Therefore you should use `wsDest.UsedRange.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row`
2. Don't name your variable `lDestLastRow` and then put the row number of the `last row + 1` that is very confusing. Name your variable according to what is in there eg `lDestNextFreeRow`
3. Fix your typos in the code `.Sheets(1)Range(B:E)` should be `.Sheets(1).Range("B:E")` and so on.
4. If you copy full columns `Range("B:E")` you can only past them in full columns otherwise you exceed the maximum rows of the sheet. Therefore limit the rows to your actual data instead of copying full columns.

   ```
   Range("B1:E1").Resize(RowSize:=lSrcLastRow)
   ```

   This will use the first cells of column `B` to `E` and then resize to the amount of rows where data was found.

Something like the following should work:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub get_data_from_file()
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Test.xslm").Worksheets("Input Sheet")
    
    Dim lDestNextFreeRow As Long 'find next free row in destination sheet
    lDestNextFreeRow = wsDest.UsedRange.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row + 1
    
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file and input range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*xls*),*xls*")
    
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Dim OpenBook As Workbook
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        
        Dim lSrcLastRow As Long 'find last used row in the source sheet
        lSrcLastRow = OpenBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("B1:E1").Resize(RowSize:=lSrcLastRow).Copy
        wsDest.Range("A" & lDestNextFreeRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("G1:H1").Resize(RowSize:=lSrcLastRow).Copy
        wsDest.Range("E" & lDestNextFreeRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("M1").Resize(RowSize:=lSrcLastRow).Copy
        wsDest.Range("G" & lDestNextFreeRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I still seem to be getting an error, it still won't paste. Runtime error 1004 -- Application defined or object defined error. :(

Comment: nevermind! this worked fantastic! I used "&" instead of the comma and it worked perfectly! many thanks!